# Can someone explain this weird behaviour in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In this code:

```
function calc(){
    this.a = 5;
}

calc(); // Run the function once

// Redefine the function
function calc(){
    return this.a;
}

// Re-run the function
calc();
// 5
```

From a guy coming from Java background.

1. How is this.a valid (if a hasn't been defined before?)
   From what I know, this.a should refer to the instance variable `a`  of the class ?
2. Why did it return `5`?

Comment: I got `undefined` in chrome.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yask123/c520d7f67f5fa5910e82

Comment: There is no such thing as a class in javascript. Javascript has nothing in common with java.

Comment: So, then what should this.a refer to ?

Comment: @user5752691 line 7 is you setting `this.a` (where `this` is the global scope) and line 19 is you reading it back

Comment: @user5752691: The 1st time you call `calc()`, you're setting `window.a` to 5.  Then you re-define the function.  Finally, you get the value of `5` that you set just before.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Weird that JS made a global variable by just setting a value to it?

Comment: You're setting 'a' as a property of 'this' (being the 'Window' object). See Mitja Kramberger's answer for more context on 'this' in Javascript

Comment: @user5752691: `this` is set based on how the function was *called*.  You called `calc()` globally, so `this` is the "global" object (or rather, `window`).  So, `this` refers to an object and you just set an `a` property on it.  Anything set on the `window` object is a global variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"this" value depends on how function was called. Inside a global function (like your example) value of "this" is equal to window object. Which means your two functions are just working with window.a (which will in your case have a value of 5).

Here you can find more information https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking you must have run your first calc before you defined and ran your second calc. 
In the first one you are initializing member a of the global object. 
In the second you are returning global.a (the global object is generally the window if you are running on a browser).

You have no class defined

Comment: [OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34640278/can-someone-explain-this-weird-behaviour-in-javascript#comment57026018_34640278) does indeed show two executions

Comment: Yea, I forgot to mention that in the question. Just one more doubt, Weird that JS made a global variable by just setting a value to it?

Answer (score 0):

@bknights is correct.  To get the behavior you're expecting, you need to `new` the function.

```
function calc(){
   this.a = 5;
}

var c = new calc();
console.log(c.a); // will return 5.

c.a = 10;
console.log(c.a); // will return 10

var b = new calc();
console.log(b.a); // will return 5 again
```